# Create files using strings which delimited by specific character in BASH

Tags: bash, loops, split

Suppose we have the following command and its related output :

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList | head -n 1 | grep -oP '(?<=\[).*?(?=\])'
```

Output :

```
'b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9', 'ca4b733c-53f2-4a7e-8a47-dce8de182546', '802e8bb8-1b78-4e1b-b97a-538d7e2f9c63', '892cd84f-9718-46ef-be06-eeda0a0550b1', '6a7d836f-b2e8-4a1e-87c9-e64e9692c8a8', '2b9e8848-0b4a-44c7-98c7-3a7e880e9b45', 'b23a4a62-3e25-40ae-844f-00fb1fc244d9'
```

I need to use gsettings command in a script and create filenames regarding to output ot gessetings command. For example a file name should be

> b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9

the next one :

> ca4b733c-53f2-4a7e-8a47-dce8de182546

and so on.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution... just pipe the output of your command to:

```
your_command | sed "s/[ ']//g" | xargs -d, touch
```

Comment: You can change your sed command to exit early and then OP could get rid of `| head -1`: `sed "s/[ ']//g;1q"`. To also replace `][` you just need to add it in the front of the character class: `sed "s/[][ ']//g;1q"` This will let OP pipe gsettings directly to sed.

Comment: @dev-null: you're 100% right. Will let OP to change his initial cmd as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use process substitution to read your gsettings output and store it in an array :

```
IFS=', ' read -r -a array < <(gsettings)
for f in "${array[@]}"
do
    file=$(echo $f |tr -d "'" ) # removes leading and trailing quotes
    touch "$file"
done
```